# How do you trigger a blur/focusout event on an input text box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, blur, focusout

I'm using 1.7.2 in which I understand this should work:

```
// cell is a jquery representation of a <td> element
cell.append($("<input/>", { "type": "text" }).val(content));        
cell.children()[0].focus();
cell.children()[0].on("blur", function() {
    alert("blur");
}
```

The input box is appended, grabs focus and then the javascript console tells me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'on'
```

I'd be grateful if anyone knows how I can catch the blur/focusout event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the DOM element with `[0]` and acting like it is a jQuery object.

If you only want the first, you need to use `eq()` to get the jQuery object.

```
cell.children().eq(0).focus().on("blur", function() {
    alert("blur");
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should bind delegate event ie. live event to those inputs, because they appended to DOM later, so they need live event handler.

```
$(cell).on('blur focusout', ':text', function() {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

then trigger like following:

```
$(':input:first', cell).blur(); // or $(':text', cell).trigger('blur');

$(':input:first', cell).focusout(); // or $(':text', cell).trigger('focusout');.
```

according to your code

```
cell.children(':input:eq(0)').focus().on("blur", function() {
    alert("blur");
};
```

or

```
cell.children(':input:first').focus().on("blur", function() {
    alert("blur");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.on` on a DOM element, not jQuery object, try this:

```
var input = $("<input/>", { "type": "text", val: content } );
cell.append(input);
input.focus();
input.on( "blur", function(){
    alert( "blur" );
});
```